# Catching Unimplemented Pure Virtuals in C++

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

As I understand it, there are the conditions under which a pure-virtual method may not be implemented on a child class, but the child class can be invoked without it resulting in a build error.

I was unable to simulate this. Does someone have any insight into how to make this happen? I've done a number of searches, but haven't been able to turn-up anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It occurs when a virtual function is called in the constructor of a base class.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base() { g();} 
    virtual ~Base() {}

    void g() { f(); }
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base() {}
    ~Derived() {}

    void f() { std::cout << "Derived f()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d; // here we have the call to the pure virtual function

    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT:

The main problem is: when a `Derived` object is constructed, the object starts as a `Base`, then the `Base::Base` constructor is executed. Since the object is still a `Base`, the call to `f()` (via `g()`) invokes `Base::f` and not `Derived::f`. After the `Base::Base` constructor completes, the object then becomes a `Derived` and the `Derived::Derived` constructor is run.

Comment: Isn't it not a good idea to call virtual functions inside constructor ?

Comment: @Pradheep Sure, it's a no no. But the above is an example doing things wrong.

Comment: @Pradheep - there's nothing wrong with calling virtual functions inside a constructor (or a destructor). The "rule" that it's a bad idea comes from people who don't understand how such a call works. It calls the version defined for the type whose constructor (or destructor) is currently running, which is not necessarily the most-derived type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought it was a matter that included not actually implementing the pure virtual. No wonder I couldn't induce an error on my own: It has to be invoked from a method from the constructor of a base. Only on SO could I get the answer to an obscure C behavior within twenty-four hours.